# Class 'Carbon\Carbon\Carbon' not found in Blade partial

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel 5.5

In my `app.php` file I have an alias defined

```
'aliases' => [
  ...
  'Carbon' => Carbon\Carbon::class,
],
```

But when trying to use it in a view, I get `Class 'Carbon\Carbon\Carbon' not found`.

```
{{ Carbon::now()->toDateString() }}
```

Only when I do `{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString() }}` does it work.

However, when I change the alias to

```
'aliases' => [
  ...
  'Carbon' => 'Carbon\Carbon',
],
```

It works as I originally intended. Why doesn't `'Carbon' => Carbon\Carbon::class,` work as expected?

Comment: Do you have `use Carbon\Carbon` in your `app.php`?

Comment: maybe alias should be 'Carbon' => \Carbon::class

Comment: @apokryfos you my friend, are a boss. I have no memory of doing that (or reason why I would), but that was it.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `Illuminate\Support\Carbon::class` instead of `Carbon\Carbon::class`.

File: `config/app.php`

```php
'aliases' => [
    ...,
    'Carbon' => Illuminate\Support\Carbon::class,
]
```

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was add

use Carbon;

to the controller.